# How to make 2 functions work at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, loading, speed-test

I am trying to make an internet speedtest app using Python and Kivy, The function that gives the internet speed needs about 30 seconds to work
So in the GUI the program stops until the function return the internet speed
How can i make a loading bar that loads while the speed test function is working ?
And can I make the function print its live results in the gui with kivy?
I searched for multithreading but I am not sure about how to use it ?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would simply start the internet speed function in another thread so GUI will not hang.

```
import threading

thread = threading.Thread(target=your_function, args=(function_arguments,))
thread.start()
```

Edit

In your case I guess you can do this

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
...
class Seventh(Widget):
    def on_button_click(self):
       self.count += 1
       self.my_var = str(self.count)
       pool = ThreadPool(1)
       async_res = pool.apply_async(self.speed.download)
       self.d = str(get_size(async_res.get()))
       print(self.d)
```

Comment: how can I apply to this code 
I will edit the post and add the code so may you check it !